# How do I delete blank rows in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-delete, delete-row

I do have a table with more than 100000 data elements, but there are almost 350 blank rows within. How do I delete this blank rows using phpmyadmin? Manually deleting is a tedious task.

Comment: Could you post your table structure, and also which field(s) should be blank for the complete record to be considered blank?

Comment: Answers from @StWilson and Thomas Williams provide the most general solutions and should have been accepted.  Spiny Norman:  comment is relevant!  the question seems to be requesting "Blank rows".  The accepted answer and NCA handle only the case with 1 blank column.  The more general solution is more complex.  DB solution from STWilson is definitely my preferred choice for this problem!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The general answer is:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column = '';
```

or

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column IS NULL;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

More info when you post your tables!~

Also, be sure to do:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE some_column = '';
```

before you delete, so you can see which rows you are deleting! I think in phpMyAdmin you can even just do the select and then "select all" and delete, but I'm not sure. This would be pretty fast, and very safe.

Comment: From the question it seems that we are interested in a "blank row",  this deletes only when one of the columns in the row is blank.

Answer (score 5):

I am doing the `mysql` operation in command prompt in windows. And the basic queries:

```
delete * from table_name where column=''
```

and

```
delete * from table_name where column='NULL'
```

doesn't work. I don't know whether it works in `phpmyadmin` sqlcommand builder. Anyway:

```
delete * from table_name where column is NULL
```

works fine.

Comment: From the question it seems that we are interested in a "blank row",  this deletes only when one of the columns in the row is blank.

Answer (score 3):

I have a PHP script that automatically removes empty rows based on column data types.

That allows me to define "emptiness" differently for different column types.

e.g.

```
table
first_name (varchar) | last_name (varchar) | some_qty ( int ) | other_qty (decimal)

DELETE FROM `table` WHERE
(`first_name` IS NULL OR `first_name` = '')
AND
(`last_name` IS NULL OR `last_name` = '')
AND
(`some_qty` IS NULL OR `some_qty` = 0)
AND
(`other_qty` IS NULL OR `other_qty` = 0)
```

Since "0" values are meaningless in my system, I count them as empty. But I found out that if you do (`first_name` = 0) then you will always get true, because strings always == 0 in MySQL. So I tailor the definition of "empty" to the data type.

Answer (score 2):

This procedure will delete any row for all columns that are null ignoring the primary column that may be set as an ID.  I hope it helps you.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteRowsAllColNull(IN tbl VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
SET @tbl = tbl;
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT CONCAT('DELETE FROM `',@tbl,'` WHERE ',(REPLACE(group_concat(concat('`',COLUMN_NAME, '` is NULL')),',',' AND ')),';') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = @tbl AND COLUMN_KEY NOT LIKE 'PRI' into @delete_all;
PREPARE delete_all FROM @delete_all;
EXECUTE delete_all;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE delete_all;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Execute the procedure like this.

```
CALL DeleteRowsAllColNull('your table');
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered and has got a tick, but I wrote a small function for doing this, and thought it might be useful to other people.

I call my function with an array so that I can use the same function for different tables.

```
$tableArray=array("Address", "Email", "Phone"); //This is the column names
$this->deleteBlankLines("tableName",$tableArray);
```

and here is the function which takes the array and builds the delete string

```
private function deleteBlankLines($tablename,$columnArray){
    $Where="";
    foreach($columnArray as $line):
        $Where.="(`".$line."`=''||`".$line."` IS NULL) && ";
    endforeach;
    $Where = rtrim($Where, '&& ');  
    $query="DELETE FROM `{$tablename}` WHERE ".$Where;
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

You can use this function for multiple tables. You just need to send in a different table name and array and it will work.

My function will check for a whole row of empty columns or NULL columns at the same time. If you don't need it to check for NULL then you can remove that part.