# DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `field`= nothing

Tags: mysql

How do I delete all rows that have a field called **A** that are blank.

Lets say I have a table that looks like the following.

```
|ID   |A   |B   |C
|1    |Data|Data|Data
|2    |    |Data|Data
|3    |Data|    |Data
|4    |    |    |
```

So in the above example row 2 and 4 would be removed because there isn't anything stored in them?

How can I do this I'm doing I'm thinking something along the lines of the following.

Okay setup another table and tried the following.

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `A`= ''
```

Is that that correct?

Comment: Did you try the query out? What were the results?

Comment: Is `A` permitted to be null or does your example show whitespace?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633321/how-do-i-delete-blank-rows-in-mysql answer your question?

Comment: Okay I just got done trying it. I had to set up another table because I didn't want to bork anything. Works good.

Comment: @BenP.Dorsi-Todaro Hehe, yes, I _fully_ understand not wanting to try arbitrary things that you aren't sure of on a live DB, especially intentionally destructive things. Glad you got it sorted. Just as a pointer, it's always good to have a relatively recent copy of the live DB around, you'd be amazed what you can learn just by trying to accomplish random things through trial and error. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell from what you provided because *...blank...* can be interpreted in various ways but may be you are looking for something like this

```
DELETE 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(COALESCE(TRIM(A), '')) = 0
```

What it does it deletes all rows that have in column A

1. `NULL` values
2. empty string values
3. values that consist of only spaces

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a451/2)** demo

Answer (score 2):

You can use both

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE A = '';
```

or

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE A IS NULL;
```

Comment: What if it's `' '` there (a string that consists of one or more spaces)?

Comment: Explain the difference between the 2 statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM TABLENAME
WHERE A IS NULL OR TRIM(A) = '';
```